# ajax no trae los datos del controlador

Tags: php, ajax, json, mvc

Buen día a todos, de antemano gracias por la ayuda

Me explico, tengo un aplicativo en el cual con MVC estoy creando la función de insertar

Este es el modelo

```
public function insert_equipo($activo,$tipo_equipo,$marca,$modelo,$serie,$usu_id,$id_sede,$estado,$caracteristicas){
    $conectar= parent::conexion();
    parent::set_names();
    $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_equipo (equ_id, activo, tipo_equipo, marca, modelo, serie, usu_id, id_sede, estado, caracteristicas, fech_crea) VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,now());";
    $sql=$conectar->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(1, $activo);
    $sql->bindValue(2, $tipo_equipo);
    $sql->bindValue(3, $marca);
    $sql->bindValue(4, $modelo);
    $sql->bindValue(5, $serie);
    $sql->bindValue(6, $usu_id);
    $sql->bindValue(7, $id_sede);
    $sql->bindValue(8, $estado);
    $sql->bindValue(9, $caracteristicas);
    $sql->execute();
}
```

Controlador

```
    switch($_GET["op"]){
    
    case "insert":
        $equipo->insert_equipo($_POST["activo"],$_POST["tipo_equipo"],$_POST["marca"],$_POST["modelo"],$_POST["serie"],$_POST["usu_id"],$_POST["id_sede"],$_POST["estado"],$_POST["caracteristicas"]);
              
    break;
```

JS de la vista

```
    function guardaryeditar(e){
e.preventDefault();
var formData = new FormData($("#equip_form")[0]);
if ($('#caracteristicas').summernote('isEmpty') || $('#activo').val()=='' || $('#tipo_equipo').val()=='' || $('#serie').val()=='' || $('#id_sede').val()=='' || $('#usuario').val()==''/*  || $('#estado').checked() */){
    swal("Advertencia!", "Campos Vacios", "warning");
}else{
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../controller/equipo.php?op=insert",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){ 
            //console.log(data);
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data[0].equ_id);

            $('#activo').val('');
            $('#tipo_equipo').val('');
            $('#marca').val('');
            $('#modelo').val('');
            $('#serie').val('');
            $('#id_sede').val('');
            $('#usuario').val('');
            $('#caracteristicas').summernote('reset');
            swal("Correcto!", "Registrado Correctamente", "success");
        }  
    }); 
}
}
```

lo que sucede es que en el JSON.parse sale error y creo que es porque no me está trayendo los datos de la vista

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

Actualizo, esta es la vista

```
<div class="row">
                <form method="post" id="equip_form">

                    <input type="hidden" id="usu_id" name="usu_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["usu_id"] ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" id="usu_nombre" name="usu_nombre" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["usu_nombre"] ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" id="usu_correo" name="usu_correo" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["usu_correo"] ?>">
                    
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label semibold" for="activo">Activo</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="activo" name="activo" placeholder="Activo del equipo">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label semibold" for="tipo_equipo">Tipo de equipo</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tipo_equipo" name="tipo_equipo" placeholder="Ingrese el tipo de equipo">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label semibold" for="marca">Marca</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="marca" name="marca" placeholder="Ingrese la marca del equipo">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label semibold" for="modelo">Modelo</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modelo" name="modelo" placeholder="Ingrese el modelo del equipo">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label semibold" for="exampleInput">Serial</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="serie" name="serie" placeholder="Serial del equipo">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label semibold" for="exampleInput">Sede</label>
                            <select id="id_sede" name="id_sede" class="form-control">
                                
                            </select>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label semibold" for="exampleInput">Usuario</label>
                            <select id="iusu_id" name="iusu_id" class="form-control">
                                
                            </select>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label semibold" for="exampleInput">Estado</label>
                            <input type="Radio" id="estado" name="estado" value="1"> Activo
                            <br>
                            <input type="Radio" id="estado" name="estado" value="0"> Dado de Baja
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label semibold" for="caracteristicas">Caracteristicas del equipo</label>
                            <div class="summernote-theme-1">
                                <textarea id="caracteristicas" name="caracteristicas" class="summernote" name="name"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <button type="submit" name="action" value="add" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

en el boton guardar está el submit que es el que en el JS llevaría la información que se va a insertar, y ya en el JS estan las instrucciones para enviar a la base de datos.

Comment: No veo que devuelvas nada del servidor

Comment: *y creo que es porque no me está trayendo los datos de la vista*, pues no vemos dónde ocurre eso en tu código, es decir, ¿dónde mandas los datos para la vista? Sólo vemos un `case` de un `switch` sin más, muestra cómo pasas la respuesta a la vista. Otra cosa, no mezcles métodos (`$_GET` y `$_POST` en este caso), aunque a veces eso funciona, en muchos contextos no. El método que definiste en la petición Ajax fue `POST`, entonces usa `$_POST` en todo en el servidor.